# Does "flounder" work for sailboats?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, vocabulary

I'm not sure if I'm using "flounder" right.

> Ms. R was familiar with Student M, the sixth grader.  She expected him to continue to **sail through** 7th grade in a similar style to 6th grade.  But in 7th grade, when expectations increased and the student began to **flounder**, Ms. R had no idea.

Is "flounder" the right verb here?  Or is there some other verb used in connection with sailboats?

I want a verb that means that the sailboat is having trouble staying upright, i.e. not capsizing.

Comment: You're looking for ***founder*** (begin to sink), but ***flounder*** works as well, both in denotation and the nautical theme.

Comment: I think ***flounder*** is, in fact, the word you are looking for. I think **founder** is just to sink/fail where *flounder* gives off the struggle you are looking for.

Comment: @Hank - Oh, I forgot about "founder."  What concerns me is that there are different types of boats.  I want to make sure the verb I choose fits naturally in the sailboat context.

Comment: @aparente001 I'm not sure if there is a term that specifically references a sailboat struggling to stay afloat. I'm not sure if such a word has ever been necessary, but it may.

Comment: @Hank - Sorry, I didn't mean to ask for a word specific to sailboats.  I just don't want to misuse a word.  I wanted to make sure that when sailboats start to have trouble, one can say that they are "floundering."  I asked at the Great Outdoors and apparently the answer is yes.  I think I better delete this question or I will get in trouble for asking questions that are too similar.

Comment: To founder is to go down, to sink (boats). To flounder is to struggle, to thrash around. Students are more likely to flounder than founder. If you fail every single exam, then you have foundered in school. If you are having problems in school, you are floundering.

Comment: @aparente001 I see no reason why it can't be used to describe a sailboat. It's a generalized word.

Comment: "Founder" means to run up on the rocks.  "Flounder" means to splash about randomly.

Comment: You may be amused by http://birdiewarbles.blogspot.com/2012/10/the-world-of-doctor-dolittle.html

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments both flounder and founder are appropriate words.

I think [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/articles/chooseyourwords/flounder-founder/) gives a good overview of the differences.

Here is their overview of **flounder**.

> A flounder is a fish, but as a verb, it means to blunder about, to be in serious trouble. In the following examples, something is struggling but hasn't completely failed...

Compared to their overview of **founder**.

> A founder is someone who starts something, but as a verb, founder literally means "to sink." Figuratively, it's "to collapse or fail completely."

So if the student is merely struggling to stay afloat then you should choose *flounder*, but if they are completely over their head and drowning then *founder* is the better word.